# Graphics card boot loop dependent on same-generation motherboard change

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I recently purchased a Geforce GT 730 to use on my Core i5 machine with an H61H2-M2 (H61 LGA 1155) motherboard, but installing it results in a startup loop where the computer fails to POST.

The screen comes alive with the BIOS logo and basic info, but it doesn't allow any input, and after a few seconds the power cuts off (no attempt to load the OS is visible). A few seconds later it attempts to start again, and the boot loop is engaged.

I transferred the card to my Core i7 machine with an MSI P67A-G45 (B3) (P67 LGA 1155) motherboard, and it worked fine. A noticeable difference was that this time the graphics card showed a brief identification screen before booting just fine, no loop.

The power supply in the i7 machine was considerably more powerful than I had in the i5, so to eliminate that variable I transferred the card and the power supply to the i5 computer, but the boot loop remained.

I suppose the most notable difference between the motherboards is the chipset, H61 vs P67. But is that really enough of a difference to decide support for a budget graphics card? What other variables decide compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appeared to be that the PCI-E slot was bad. A new motherboard solved the issue.